Connecting QGIS to Google Cloud DB Project (MobilityDB)
I would like to visualize data from MobilityDB queries which are being performed with GCP, but do not know how to connect the database to QGIS in this case. I tried passing the External IP of a VM instance as a PostGIS host IP (since MobilityDB is based on PostGIS) but connection failed.
I also have a MOVE plugin installed but do not know how to first connect to the database.

PostGIS is just the spatial type extension, so I hope MobilityDB is based on PostgreSQL.   The default security model for PostgreSQL is to deny all non-localhost connections, so you'll need more than just the IP to establish communication, and will probably need some OS and/or firewall configuration changes as well.  If you can get a vanilla PG client like psql to connect, then QGIS connectivity would be a breeze. You may want to research PG configuration details, which would be more in the domain of [dba.se].
